# SpellChecking , Highlighting Misspelled Word , Suggestions for Angular Form Group

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, typescript

#### Creating my Own Spell Checking Service in Angular

- this is my from

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mat-field-full-width">
 <mat-label>MOC Title (Min 15 and Max 150 characters)</mat-label>
  <input spellcheck="true" (input)="checkSpelling()" formControlName="moctitle" matInput placeholder="Enter Title Here" #moctitle required minlength="15" maxlength="150" rows="1">
  <span class="form-text text-muted"><code>{{moctitle.value.length}}/150</code></span>
</mat-form-field>
```

- this below is my ts file that i m using checkSpelling()

```
  checkSpelling(text: string): void {
    this.spellcheckerService.checkSpelling(text);
    this.misspellings = this.spellcheckerService.getMisspellings();
    this.highlightedText = this.spellcheckerService.highlightMisspelledWords();
    console.log(this.misspellings);
    console.log(this.highlightedText)
    // Call getSuggestions for each misspelled word
    this.suggestions = this.misspellings.reduce((suggestions, misspelledWord) => {
      const wordSuggestions = this.spellcheckerService.getSuggestions(misspelledWord);
      return suggestions.concat(wordSuggestions);
    }, [] as string[]); // Provide an initial value as an empty array
    console.log(this.suggestions)
  }
```

- what i want is , i want to highlight the misspelled word in text inside input and when i click on that word i want to show the suggestions i have a showsuggestions() function as well . please help me
- below is my code that i m currently using

```
<!-- Display the highlighted text -->
- this is how i m showing misspelled values but instead of this i want this inside Above formcontrol 
<div [innerHTML]="highlightedText" (click)="showSuggestions($event)"></div>

showSuggestions(event: any): void {

  if (event.target && event.target.classList.contains('misspelled-word')) {

    const misspelledWord = event.target.getAttribute('data-word');

    const suggestions = this.getSuggestions(misspelledWord); // Implement your suggestion logic here

    // Show the suggestions and allow the user to replace the word

    // You can use a dialog, a menu, or another UI element for this.

  }

}
```